# Make windows stand-alone executable file for spring boot project and angular project which can access offline in windows

Tags: java, postgresql, exe

I have one jar file which bundles with UI now I want to make one standalone window executable file. in the jar file, I have code with PostgreSQL database tomcat server
my pom file for the project like

I want only one exe which has run directly on double click

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>dev.marco</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-angular-example</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
       ....
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>dev.marco.ShlowinApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
...
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of would be launch4j, adding an exe launcher for your application. This will add the exe, but will not magically make it a desktop-application, for that you may need to adjust code.

A configuration in the pom.xml would look similar to the following:

```xml
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>l4j-gui</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>launch4j</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <headerType>gui</headerType>
                                    <outfile>target/${project.artifactId}.exe</outfile>
                                    <jar>target/${project.artifactId}.jar</jar>
                                    <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
                                    <addDependencies>true</addDependencies>
                                    <errTitle>Error in launch4j plugin</errTitle>
                                    <classPath>
                                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                                    </classPath>
                                    <icon>src/main/resources/Images/logo.ico</icon>
                                    <jre>
                                        <path>./java</path>
                                    </jre>
                                    <versionInfo>
                                        <fileVersion>${project.version}.0</fileVersion>
                                        <txtFileVersion>${project.version}.0</txtFileVersion>
                                        <fileDescription>${description}</fileDescription>
                                        <copyright>Copyright(c) ${distributor}</copyright>
                                        <companyName>${distributor}</companyName>
                                        <productVersion>${project.version}.0</productVersion>
                                        <txtProductVersion>${project.version}.0</txtProductVersion>
                                        <productName>${project.artifactId}</productName>
                                        <internalName>${project.artifactId}</internalName>
                                        <originalFilename>${project.artifactId}.exe</originalFilename>
                                        <language>ENGLISH_UK</language>
                                    </versionInfo>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

Comment: What if I install exe in windows which has no java and PostgreSQL installed in the machine how to embedded all this thing in one exe ?

Comment: can't answer PostgreSQL, but java here is expected to be in ./java relatively to the exe. That means your installer can provide it.